# tensorflow: how to recognize untrained new letter

Tags: tensorflow

I just get a question. I want the system to return the -1 as unknown char for the new untrained letters. For example, if I have trained 1/2/3/4，when I test the char '5' or '6', the tensorflow should return -1 as unknown char.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think for simple classifications, you're looking for anything that has less than a certain confidence/score of being a known class.

To be fair, I've only use Keras on top of TensorFlow, so YMMV.

I'd just train it on the 4 categories you know, then when it classifies if the final results if the top one has less than a certain raw score/weight (let's say it classifies an unknown 7 as a 4, but with a mediocre score) treat it as a -1.

This might not work with every loss/objection function you train your model on, but should work MSE or categorical cross entropy if you can get the raw final weight.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but sometime the trained letter would be recognized as unknown -1 also:(